# Considering the Order of Execution, Can a Manually Entered Record through the UI ever be in a Queue Before Insert?

Tags: user, assignment-rules, ui, order-of-execution

**Background:** I've been building a Lead round robin system to evenly distribute work. It checks for records owned by queues, and assigns them to the next user available in each queue. I opted to do a lot of work **before insert**, so that I could shuffle records around without extra DML.

However, I (incorrectly) assumed that Lead Assignment Rules happened much earlier in the order of execution, so none of my **before insert** code is finding any records in a queue. I didn't realize at first, because I had similar code in the **before update** logic which was catching the records that I **thought** were being handled **before insert**, so things appeared to be working in tests, until I started building my assertions.

---

**This got me thinking of the following question:**

> Considering the Order of Execution
>   (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm),
>   Before and After triggers all run PRIOR to Assignment Rules. Workflows
>   and Process Builders also run after the before triggers. Since
>   Assignment Rules count as a workflow field update, **before update**
>   and **after update** triggers run one more time after the record has
>   been assigned to the queue, which is when my code actually picks them
>   up and runs it through round robin.
>
> When a user creates a record themselves, they own it by default. Even
>   if they check the box to run active assignment rules, it follows the
>   same order. It will always run before triggers prior to any other
>   updates that would change the ownership to a queue.
>
> So, assuming SF doesn't change this order - Is it safe to say that it
>   is 100% impossible for a record inserted manually through the
>   **Salesforce UI (specifically)** to ever be owned by a queue **BEFORE INSERT**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following axioms, it is 100% guaranteed impossible that the Owner would be a Queue.

- The record is created manually through the User Interface.
- There are no before insert triggers that alter the OwnerId.
- The records are not imported through an API or Import Wizard.
- The records are not created through code.

Once you start customizing Salesforce or using more advanced features, this would no longer be true.

Comment: Fox can you clarify this last bit "Once you start customizing or using more advanced features". The advanced features you are referring to I assume are API and Data Load/Import inserts? I already know that those methods would allow me to insert a record directly in queue (which justifies me keeping my Before Insert logic), just wanted to make sure there were no other non-programmatic ways to have a record START in a queue when entered by an end-user.

Comment: @MorganMarchese Yes, that's what I meant to imply. Short of programming or using API  calls, it is 100% impossible for any record to start in a queue by the time a *before insert* trigger fires.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it safe to say that it is 100% impossible for a record inserted manually through the Salesforce UI (specifically) to ever be owned by a queue BEFORE INSERT?

A `before insert` would mean that the record hasn't been saved yet to a database. The record comes to existence in the database only once the `before insert` triggers have been executed. Depending on when you are assigning the Owner for the record, the value will come to existence only when you have a record in the database.

So theoretically there is no way that a record which is not yet in existent to be owned by a Queue unless you assign the Owner's value during the operation as a Queue.

Comment: That is true, but even in the before insert context there is an OwnerId assigned to the record, even if it is still only a record in memory and not yet committed. My question was less about whether it exists in the DB and more about whether there was some SF native "clicks-not-code" method to insert a record directly into a queue outside of an API or Apex transaction. Sounds like the answer is no.

Comment: Even if say you have an OwnerId assigned during before insert operation, the record will *get into the queue* only when it gets persisted. As long as it's in memory, it cannot be owned by the queue/or any other owner. So yes, the answer to your question is no.